# Forward slash insert a period on terminal

Tags: terminal, vagrant, phpstorm, ubuntu-14.04, keyboard-layout

I'm Running Vagrant 2.0.2, Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 Pro

My Keyboard Layout is PT BR

I'm having trouble running Ubuntu trusty64 on Vagrant on Windows 10 64, I enter the VM with `vagrant ssh` but when I'm in VM and type `/` a period appear on terminal, if I press `/` twice a get a listing of current dir.

[image: forward_slash_strange_behavior]

when I'm editing a file in the vim or nano `/` works normally.

[image: forward_slash_on_vim]

I've tried to set keyboard layout to PT-BR but it still has the same behaviour.

#### EDIT

I've tried to SSH VM in the ConEmu and it works, seems to be a problem with the PhpStorm Integrated Shell itself, where I was trying to run the commands.

Comment: does it happen only in terminal? Would it work if you switch to EN-US?

Comment: I didn't try to switch to en-US, It only happens inside vagrant VM when using PhpStorm integrated terminal running Powershell, but not if I'm editing some text (inside vim, nano, etc.)

Comment: please do try. You might want to report this at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes for developers/support team to look into